# Color code a data table in dc.js

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I have a vary basic question and very little understanding of dc.js.
I am trying to create a score card using the data that i have and display it as a data table using dc.js.I am processing the data through crossfilter.

**How can i color code the entries in the data table**. Say my table will have values from -1 to 1 and i want to color the cells as follows:
    -1 to 0 : decreasing gradient of red
     0 : white
     0 to 1 : increasing gradient of green

I know i am not able to provide any code but thats because i am at a total loss on how to achieve this. Help will be really appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Another, more hacky, but d3-based answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156839/how-to-color-code-rows-in-a-table-dc-datatable/29172240#29172240

Comment: This is great Gordon :) Thanks a ton

Comment: @Gordon: Hey Gordon, Sorry for calling you out but could you please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29266793/dc-js-choropleth-filtering-issue
Its been a week and  i have tried almost everything. FInally had to replace choropleth with a leaflet based dc chart but why choropleth didnt work is still bugging me. Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with css.

I'm using datatables jquery plugin.

```
{ targets: 3, 
data: function (d) {
    if (d.Rating<5) {       return '<span class="red">'+d.Rating+'</span>' ;}
    else if (d.Rating<7) {  return '<span class="yellow">'+d.Rating+'</span>' ;}
    else if (d.Rating<=10) {return '<span class="green">'+d.Rating+'</span>' ;}
    else {                  return '<span class="grey">'+d.Rating+'</span>' ;}
}}
```

you can make as much categories as you want.
And modify appearence with css like this.

```
.red{ background-color:red; }
.yellow{ background-color:yellow; }
.green{ background-color:green; }
```

Comment: That part worked out but i am now looking for a gradient style implementation, would not be ideal to hard code colour values for every decimal from -1 to 1. Any ideas?

Comment: That's only 21 categories. I would use the same technique with `switch` instead of `if else`. With sublime text and multiple cursors it's not more difficult to write 100 categories than 3.

Comment: You are right. For this case i could do that :) However in future if the same kinda thing happens and i am talking of a large gradient should i write a function?.. On the other hand 100 categories would cover almost anything :)