# How to color code rows in a table dc.datatable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dc.js

On the [DC.js github](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki), [Stock Market Selection Strategy by Lon Riesberg](http://www.acrodatics.com/) is listed as an example of using the dc.js library.

He was able to color code the rows, as shown in the image below, which I'm trying to mimic.

[image]

See here for my code: http://codepen.io/chriscruz/pen/myaWvR?editors=101

In particular, how would I change the color of the rows so that all rows with the name 'Red' are red, with the name 'Blue' are Blue, and the name 'White' are white.

Javascript:

```
items = [
            {Id: "01", Name: "Red", Price: "1.00", Quantity: "1",TimeStamp:111},
            {Id: "02", Name: "White", Price: "10.00", Quantity: "1",TimeStamp:222},
            {Id: "04", Name: "Blue", Price: "9.50", Quantity: "10",TimeStamp:434},
            {Id: "03", Name: "Red", Price: "9.00", Quantity: "2",TimeStamp:545},
            {Id: "06", Name: "White", Price: "100.00", Quantity: "2",TimeStamp:676},
            {Id: "05",Name: "Blue", Price: "1.20", Quantity: "2",TimeStamp:777}
        ];

var ndx = crossfilter(items);


var Dim = ndx.dimension(function (d) {return d.Name;})
dc.dataTable("#Table")
  .width(250).height(800)
  .dimension(Dim)
  .group(function(d) {return ' '})
  .size(100)             // number of rows to return
  .columns([
  function(d) { return d.Id;},
  function(d) { return d.Name;},
  function(d) { return d.Price;},
  function(d) { return d.Quantity;},
  function(d) { return d.TimeStamp;},

])
  .sortBy(function(d){ return d.Price;})
  .order(d3.ascending);
dc.renderAll();
```

HTML:

```
<table class='table table-hover' id='Table'>
  <thead>
    <tr class='header'>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Timestamp</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

How could this be done considering the only attributes that [dc.js](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-1.6.0.md#data-table) has are size, columns, sortBy, and order?

Comment: You can use the `renderlet` call to do this.  See https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-1.6.0.md#renderletrenderletfunction

Comment: Thanks - that helps a lot, but I can't seem to get renderlet to work - see my code here: http://codepen.io/chriscruz/pen/myaWvR?editors=101

Comment: A css and jquery based answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28807699/color-code-a-data-table-in-dc-js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You had a syntax error and an unknown symbol in your codepen there. The idea is to use `chart.selectAll` to grab the rows, and then color them based on the data somehow:

```
.renderlet(function(chart){
    chart.selectAll('tr.dc-table-row')
         .style('background-color', function(d) { 
             return d ? d.Name : null; 
         })
});
```

[image: table with colors]

Here's my fork: http://codepen.io/gordonwoodhull/pen/pvqpVV

Comment: fwiw i poked into Lon's code and he is generating the table using straight d3, not using the dc.js datatable. but it's basically the same as i show above.