# Is it possible to create a sortable table with dc.js that has conditional formatting?

Tags: dc.js

For a table like this: https://www.intothevoid.io/data-visualization/sortable-table-dc-js/.

Ideally I am looking for conditional formatting with colored rowbars, but if not, just different colored cells based on values.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Is there another example of the kind of conditional formatting you are looking for? Have you tried to put something together? It helps if you can give a little bit more of a lead to potential answerers.

Comment: This question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156839/how-to-color-code-rows-in-a-table-dc-datatable - you'd just need to combine it with the example you linked.