# dc.js Data Table Coloring

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I have a vary basic question related to dc.js Data Tables. I have created a data table having 3 columns including the state name, meanQRT and study.

**How can I color the second column according to their values without sorting** them. For Example the lowest meanQRT value will have red color and the highest will have the green color and the values range between -1 to 1.

I don't think its a good option to hard code the color values as well.

Currently I have sorted the table using meanQRT value and given the table percent to rgb color

***I don't want to hard code the value by particular color. As I have 96 rows in my data I want to give a different color to all the rows starting from red to the gradients of green on the basis of their increasing value where my data in the table is not sorted.***

```
     dc.dataTable("#rbm-data-table", "newView")
                    .dimension(stateName)
                    .group(function (d) {
                        return "Country " + ": " + d.Country;
                    })
                    .size(96)
                    .columns([
                        function (d) {
                            return d.State;
                        },
                        function (d) {
                            return d.meanQRT;
                        },
                        function (d) {
                            return d.Study;
                        }
                     ])                    
                    .order(d3.descending)
                    /*
                    .sortBy(function (d) { 
                                            return d.meanQRT;
                                        })*/


                    .renderlet(function(table){
                        table.selectAll('.dc-table-group').classed("info", true);
                        colorCode();
                    });

        dc.renderAll("newView");

function colorCode(){
    function percentToRGB(percent) {
        if (percent === 100) {
            percent = 99;
        }
        var r, g, b;

        if (percent < 50) {
            // green to yellow
            r = Math.floor(255 * (percent / 50));
            g = 255;

        } else {
            // yellow to red
            r = 255;
            g = Math.floor(255 * ((50 - percent % 50) / 50));
        }
        b = 0;

        return "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
    }   

    function render(i) {        
        //$('.dc-table-row:nth-child('+ i +')').css('background-color', percentToRGB(i));
        $('.dc-table-row:nth-child('+ i +') td:nth-child(2)').css('background-color', percentToRGB(i));
        $('.dc-table-row:nth-child('+ i +') td:nth-child(3)').css('background-color', percentToRGB(i));

    }

    function repeatColor(fn, times) {
        for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
            fn(i);
            }
    }

    var colorCount = 96;
    repeatColor(render, colorCount);

    }
```

Thank You.

Comment: Here is the exact same question for table rows, just a few days ago. Does it help? http://stackoverflow.com/q/29156839/676195

Comment: Also same as here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28807699/color-code-a-data-table-in-dc-js/28857599#28857599

Comment: I don't want to hard code the value by particular color. As I have 96 rows in my data I want to give a different color to all the rows starting from red to the gradients of green on the basis of their increasing value where my data in the table is not sorted.

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#linear_domain

Comment: I have added the fiddle for my question. http://jsfiddle.net/AartiGupta/3nm9fsLe/8/ Here the riskIndicator values are not sorted whereas the color range is sorted. But I want the color according to the value not from top to bottom.

Comment: To get around this issue maybe you could put all the values in an array, sort it, and then add a rank index to them, and then push the rank index to the array you use for crossfiltering. I know this is inefficient, but with a rank variable you should be able to accomplish the coloring